# How to find out how many times identity column is RESEEDED

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, identity-column

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, I can reset the identity by using the `DBCC RESEED` command, or by using a `Truncate table` statement.

Is there any information stored about how many times identity value of column has been reseeded?

Comment: No. This isn't stored anywhere. why would you need it?

Comment: to do some analysis and surveillance on table

Comment: give example,what do you want ? we can count how many times identity columns are not continuous.it may give us some idea.

Comment: @KumarHarsh  - eg. I truncated table where Identity will get  reset  and then explicitely reset identity by DBCC command so in all it is two time I am resetting Identity, I want to know where this count is stored i.e. no. of time table getting reseed.

Comment: you have very special requirement and you yourself reseeding it.then why don't you store the info before reseeding it.

Comment: Yes that is last option , I am doing.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can not get this information from sql server. once you reseed then will be updated. For more details check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)